# Laravel Backpack update Datatable via ajax when select field change

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am new to Laravel Backpack. I have a view where I have to show some details of a category, I have a dropdown list of categories on top and datatable below it listing all the details I want to update this data table when any category is selected and I want it use ajax so that it wont load the page again.

I was unable to get any clue from the documents. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel backpack v4 as far I know you can use the variable `crud` and by calling this `crud.table.draw()`

You can see the file in datatables_logic.blade.php.

[image: image: datables.logic.blade.php]

```
JQuery(document).ready(function($){
   crud.table = $("#crudTable").DataTable(crud.dataTableConfiguration);
   ...
)}
```